# Save cv::Mat values gotten in for loop to a 2D array

Tags: c++

I'm a novice in c++. I want to read dcm files in a folder and concatenate the pixels of each file as a 2-D vector.
Like...

```
vector img_processing(string path){
    /* 
    1. Read dcm by path.
    2. Dcm to cv::Mat.
    3. cv::Mat to vector<Uint16> A.
    4. return A;
    */
}

int main(){
    vector<string> files; // A vector contains file paths.
    vector<vector<Uint16>> array;
    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++){
        array.push_back(img_processing(files[i]);
    }
    // Process array...
}
```

But I found that I can't get values of files except last one. So I want to know if there exists a method to keep local vector value in a for loop to an array that can be call by outside the for loop?

It looked like this.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "keep local vector value in a for loop to an array that can be call by outside the for loop" ? And why can't you "get values of files except last one"?

Comment: @Botje I found that the values of vector<Uint16> A will be replaced in each loop.  
If I set `vector<vector<Uint16>> array(files.size());` and print array after the for loop. I will get 0,0,0,0,...,0,values of A.

Comment: Because that creates an array of size N(=files.size()) with default values, and you then `push_back` some more vectors. But the code you showed here does not suffer from that, so what is your question?

Comment: I want to save pixels of each file as a vector and stack them as a 2D vector.

Comment: ... and that is what the code you showed does. Unless your question is actually about `img_processing`?

Comment: I added the result picture. Only the last row of array has values.

Comment: Your code is missing vital error checking information. What happens if a file fails to load for whatever reason? I bet it returns an empty `cv::Mat` that your code happily turns into an empty `std::vector`.

Comment: Don't post code as images if you want to get an answer to your question. Post that image as code.

Comment: for debug purposes if you modify the function that loads the image files and converts them to vectors such that it displays the images, do you see the images you expect?